# Obtaining PhotoHunt code which is no longer on GitHub

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github, google-plus

I'm looking to obtain the code for PhotoHunt python (and eventually js and android), however the page on GitHub is no longer found https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-photohunt-server-python Is there a way I can still retrieve this?

The tutorial is given here https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [the search option](https://github.com/search?q=photohunt&type=Repositories), I found one fork: https://github.com/nixtish/gplus-photohunt-server-python

You'll need to check whether its history is sane, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems like a really obvious thing to do now.